# How to show ellipsis for a content

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I am building an `Ionic3/Angular` application and i have a list of cards of some notes like below:

[image]

So, you can see that my notes can be larger than the width of the card. So, it has been truncated as ellipsis using **ion-item**.

```
<ion-col col-11 class="padding-0">
     <ion-item class="padding-left-0">{{noteInfo.Notes}}</ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

But, the problem is that **Notes** are not always plain string like "**This is test**". It can be a **HTML** element like

```
<span style='color:red'>This is test</span>
```

and the note may be larger than this simple note. As the note will be HTML element, i change my code for showing the note in the card like below:

```
<ion-col col-11 class="padding-0">
                    <ion-item class="padding-left-0" [innerHTML]="progressNote[0].HTMLNotes | safeHtml:'html'">
                    </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

And the output is:

[image]

But, i have an expand button for every note and if i click on that the actual note is like below:

[image]

Now, you can see that setting the HTML in the **innerHTML** of **ion-item**, it does not show ellipsis if the notes is larger than the width. But, i need to show only a preview in the card and that preview needs to be colored.

So, is there any way to show the HTML element in an ion-item so that it takes as much as the width can fit in the card and then show ellipsis for rest of the content?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/9sj8d5b5/6/) of a div with content that acts as you wish, you can apply the CSS rules on your ion-col.

**HTML**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="item">
  short text
 </div>
  <div class="item">
  long text wrgj rgoiherg eroighe goeirhg rgirg rgihreg
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.card{
  width: 200px;
}

.item{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Your solution will not gonna work. Suppose, inside <div class="item">, "long text wrgj rgoiherg eroighe goeirhg rgirg rgihreg" is not a simple text. It is an HTML like <span style="color: red">long text</span> wrgj rgoiherg eroighe goeirhg rgirg rgihreg. Now will the ellipsis work as expected when it crosses the width of the div>

Answer (score 0):

Check [ellipsis-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ellipsis-angular) npm package.
Using it you may add ellipsis automatically if HTML content overflows container.

Installation: `npm i ellipsis-angular`

Usage example:

```html
<div ellipsis-angular>
<!-- Static HTML content goes here ---> 
</div>
```

or

```html
<div ellipsis-angular [innerHTML]="someHTMLStringVariable"></div>
```

for dynamic html.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33346640)